# Serial program runs slower with multiple instances or in parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, fortran, gfortran, gnu-parallel

I have a fortran code that I am using to calculate some quantities related to the work that I do. The code itself involves several nested loops, and requires very little disk I/O. Whenever the code is modified, I run it against a suite of several input files (just to make sure it's working properly).

To make a long story short, the most recent update has increased the run time of the program by about a factor of four, and running each input file serially with one CPU takes about 45 minutes (a long time to wait, just to see whether anything was broken). Consequently, I'd like to run each of the input files in parallel across the 4 cpus on the system. I've been attempting to implement the parallelism via a bash script.

The interesting thing I have noted is that, when only one instance of the program is running on the machine, it takes about three and a half minutes to crank through one of the input files. When four instances of the program are running, it takes more like eleven and a half minute to crank through one input file (bringing my total run time down from about 45 minutes to 36 minutes - an improvement, yes, but not quite what I had hoped for).

I've tried implementing the parallelism using gnu parallel, xargs, wait, and even just starting four instances of the program in the background from the command line. Regardless of how the instances are started, I see the same slow down. Consequently, I'm pretty sure this isn't an artifact of the shell scripting, but something going on with the program itself.

I have tried rebuilding the program with debugging symbols turned off, and also using static linking. Neither of these had any noticeable impact. I'm currently building the program with the following options:

$ gfortran -Wall -g -O3 -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow,underflow,denormal -fbounds-check -finit-real=nan -finit-integer=nan -o [program name] {sources}

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you are using GNU Parallel Shell? If not please check the descritptions of your tags and use only those which apply. Also, is the bash tag really relevant? Some code will be probably necessary.

Comment: Yes, I have tried using GNU parallel as a solution. I have also tried using xargs, wait, and simply launching multiple instances in the background.

Comment: Do you have four hardware cores?  Is your program memory bandwidth heavy?  Please provide more specific information on your hardware and an example program.

Comment: Your program could be not CPU bound, but limited by memory bandwidth or could rely on some shared resource, i.e. NFS might be serializing file access. What kind of CPUs do you have?

Comment: The CPU is an Intel i5-6500, four cores @ 3.2 GHz. I'm just running on the single CPU, so NFS shouldn't be interfering. The memory bandwidth makes sense, and that might be where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 1):

On modern CPUs you cannot expect a linear speedup. There are several reasons:

- **Hyperthreading** GNU/Linux will see hyperthreading as a core eventhough it is not a real core. It is more like 30% of a core.
- **Shared caches** If your cores share the same cache and a single instance of your program uses the full shared cache, then you will get more cache misses if you run more instances.
- **Memory bandwidth** A similar case as the shared cache is the shared memory bandwidth. If a single thread uses the full memory bandwidth, then running more jobs in parallel may congest the bandwidth. This can partly be solved by running on a NUMA where each CPU has some RAM that is "closer" than other RAM.
- **Turbo mode** Many CPUs can run a single thread at a higher clock rate than multiple threads. This is due to heat.

All of these will exhibit the same symptom: Running a single thread will be faster than each of the multiple threads, but the total throughput of the multiple threads will be bigger than the single thread.

Though I must admit your case sounds extreme: With 4 cores I would have expected a speedup of at least 2.

**How to identify the reason**

- **Hyperthreading** Use `taskset` to select which cores to run on. If you use 2 of the 4 cores is there any difference if you use #1+2 or #1+3?
- **Turbo mode** Use `cpufreq-set` to force a low frequency. Is the speed now the same if you run 1 or 2 jobs in parallel?
- **Shared cache** Not sure how to do this, but if it is somehow possible to disable the cache, then comparing 1 job to 2 jobs run at the same low frequency should give an indication.

Comment: -fbounds-check does not make the code run faster, and some of the other -Wall also slow things down. I do not know how one works of cache misses without the few products that are designed explicitly for that.

Comment: Using `taskset` and forcing the four instances to run on two CPUs results in a slightly longer clock time compared to four instances on four CPUs (12.5 minutes compared to 11 minutes). The CPU time is significantly shorter when the four instances run on two CPU (6.25 minutes compared to 10.67 minutes).

Comment: Can you run 2 jobs on 2 cores, but try core #1+2 and then #1+3. Is there a difference?

Comment: 2 jobs 2 cores: Using cores 1+2 the whole set of test inputs completed in 36 minutes 14 seconds (compared to ~36 minutes running 4 jobs on 4 cores and 44 minutes running 1 job on 1 core). Using cores 1+3 the set completed in 39 minutes 6 seconds.