# PHP program making calls to Bash in parallel on AWS is slow

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a PHP repository on AWS. When I run a script in parallel (multiple instances of the same script that consume different data but perform the same computation on them), it runs about 3-4x slower than when it is run on my computer.

To test this out, I created a toy example which I ran on both my AWS server (8 CPUs, 16 GB RAM; 2x.large) and on my computer with the same configuration.

I compile a simple Java program using `shell_exec` in PHP and dump the timestamps before and after the compile in a file, to keep a track of the time taken.

The Java program is obtained from [Rosetta Code](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Java) and eight copies of the source file are made. Additional files are:

**compile1.sh**

```
javac HoughTransform1.java
```

**compile2.sh**

```
javac HoughTransform2.java
```

(and so forth up to compile8.sh)

**run_compile.php**

```
<?php
$daemonId = $argv[1];
$output = shell_exec("date");
file_put_contents("daemon-$daemonId.log", trim($output) . ": daemon $daemonId started\n", FILE_APPEND);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $output = shell_exec("date");
    file_put_contents("daemon-$daemonId.log", trim($output) . ": Compile $i Started\n", FILE_APPEND);
    exec("./compile" . $daemonId . ".sh", $out, $exit);
    $output = shell_exec("date");
    file_put_contents("daemon-$daemonId.log", trim($output) . ": Compile $i Finished\n", FILE_APPEND);
    
}
?>
```

**runall.sh**

```
nohup php run_compile.php 1 &
nohup php run_compile.php 2 &
nohup php run_compile.php 3 &
nohup php run_compile.php 4 &
nohup php run_compile.php 5 &
nohup php run_compile.php 6 &
nohup php run_compile.php 7 &
nohup php run_compile.php 8 &
```

What I notice in the logs generated is that it takes about 2-4 seconds for compiling. Below is a sample of the log written by the first process:

```
Mon Apr  2 14:45:29 IST 2018: daemon 1 started
Mon Apr  2 14:45:29 IST 2018: Compile 1 Started
Mon Apr  2 14:45:31 IST 2018: Compile 1 Finished
Mon Apr  2 14:45:31 IST 2018: Compile 2 Started
Mon Apr  2 14:45:34 IST 2018: Compile 2 Finished
Mon Apr  2 14:45:34 IST 2018: Compile 3 Started
Mon Apr  2 14:45:36 IST 2018: Compile 3 Finished
Mon Apr  2 14:45:36 IST 2018: Compile 4 Started
Mon Apr  2 14:45:39 IST 2018: Compile 4 Finished
Mon Apr  2 14:45:39 IST 2018: Compile 5 Started
Mon Apr  2 14:45:41 IST 2018: Compile 5 Finished
Mon Apr  2 14:45:41 IST 2018: Compile 6 Started
Mon Apr  2 14:45:43 IST 2018: Compile 6 Finished
Mon Apr  2 14:45:43 IST 2018: Compile 7 Started
Mon Apr  2 14:45:46 IST 2018: Compile 7 Finished
Mon Apr  2 14:45:46 IST 2018: Compile 8 Started
Mon Apr  2 14:45:48 IST 2018: Compile 8 Finished
Mon Apr  2 14:45:48 IST 2018: Compile 9 Started
Mon Apr  2 14:45:50 IST 2018: Compile 9 Finished
Mon Apr  2 14:45:50 IST 2018: Compile 10 Started
Mon Apr  2 14:45:53 IST 2018: Compile 10 Finished
```

There is a lag in all the processes on AWS.
However, when I run the same on my own computer, it runs faster

```
Mon Apr  2 16:16:49 IST 2018: daemon 1 started
Mon Apr  2 16:16:49 IST 2018: Compile 1 Started
Mon Apr  2 16:16:50 IST 2018: Compile 1 Finished
Mon Apr  2 16:16:50 IST 2018: Compile 2 Started
Mon Apr  2 16:16:51 IST 2018: Compile 2 Finished
Mon Apr  2 16:16:51 IST 2018: Compile 3 Started
Mon Apr  2 16:16:52 IST 2018: Compile 3 Finished
Mon Apr  2 16:16:52 IST 2018: Compile 4 Started
Mon Apr  2 16:16:53 IST 2018: Compile 4 Finished
Mon Apr  2 16:16:53 IST 2018: Compile 5 Started
Mon Apr  2 16:16:54 IST 2018: Compile 5 Finished
Mon Apr  2 16:16:54 IST 2018: Compile 6 Started
Mon Apr  2 16:16:55 IST 2018: Compile 6 Finished
Mon Apr  2 16:16:55 IST 2018: Compile 7 Started
Mon Apr  2 16:16:55 IST 2018: Compile 7 Finished
Mon Apr  2 16:16:55 IST 2018: Compile 8 Started
Mon Apr  2 16:16:56 IST 2018: Compile 8 Finished
Mon Apr  2 16:16:56 IST 2018: Compile 9 Started
Mon Apr  2 16:16:57 IST 2018: Compile 9 Finished
Mon Apr  2 16:16:57 IST 2018: Compile 10 Started
Mon Apr  2 16:16:58 IST 2018: Compile 10 Finished
```

I looked into the questions posted before
[Why amazon EC2 is as slow as my machine when running python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607466/why-amazon-ec2-is-as-slow-as-my-machine-when-running-python-code?rq=1)

[Serial program runs slower with multiple instances or in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40753070/serial-program-runs-slower-with-multiple-instances-or-in-parallel)

but it was of no help.

What is the issue and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Issue could be Disk IO?  Have you taken a look at the CloudWatch Metrics for the EBS drive attached to your instance (seperate to the EC2 metrics for the server)?What size & type is the EBS volume? (as that impacts the available IOP's).

See AWS docs on EBS volume types and limits: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html

Comment: Took a look at CloudWatch Metrics. It didn't show high IOPs usage. There is no blockage there. We are using a GP2 SSD with a capacity of 25 GB. So, disk IO doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: When you say "didn't show high IOPS" what were you comparing to? Are you aware that IOPS is limited by the size of the disk?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you used the `time` command and logged its output, rather than simple start/finish compile times. It will show you the CPU and System time in addition to clock time.

Comment: "didn't show high IOPS" IOPs were under the limit. Also, this question is specifically aimed at the scripts mentioned in the question. There isn't much IO in the scripts above.